# Report export to pdf

Tags: ms-access, pdf, export, report, hidden-field

Good morning,
I am having an "interesting" experience with reports and exporting them to pdf.
I've created a report that hides specific fields based on a condition.  The fields hide (as they should) in print preview and also when I export to Word but when I export to pdf, they all re-appear. It is the same result for ANY fields I hide manually as well.

Anyone know why and have a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: pl upload image to dropbox and share the public url.

Comment: Thank you - I added a link to a screen capture.

Comment: Did you try to do this in i.e. Access 2010 and 2013? It might help to find out is this is an Access bug or if you are missing something. It would also help if you publish your code how you hide specific fields.

Comment: I am doing this in Access 2007 and do not have any other version available to me to try....

Comment: Also, this is an example of what I am using in vba that is supposed to hide the text "PROMO CODE" and they are under 'On Load'.

'If [Promo_Contest] = True Then Label116.Visible = False

Answer (score 0):

When you export to PDF, the report is recreated, i.e. the program code is re-executed (although this is not visible as it does stop on debug breakpoints). The Sub Report_Open however is NOT re-executed. As a result, fields being initialized there, will not be initialized during the export to pdf.
I resolved this by initializing the fields again in the sub ReportFooter_Format, i.e. at the end of the report.